# axios delete route not supported laravel vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have a very strange issue with deleteing records. In my vuejs I call axios.delete to delete my record, which in turn calls my laravel route.

The record is getting deleted fine but an error message is displaying "message": "The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.",

```
axios.delete('/member/event/' + this.data.module.slug);
```

My laravel route is as follows

```
Route::resource('event', 'EventController');
```

I am using laravel 6 to

Comment: You should use `php artisan route:list` to see the list of registered routes. Otherwise could you post your whole `routes/web.php`? We don't see if it's prefixed with `/member` for your `event` resource routes.

Comment: Can you post your Destroy method signature?   Does it look something like this?  `public function destroy(\YourNameSpace\Event $event)`  Also, if possible, I suggest your model name from `Event` to something else to prevent conflict.  There are just too many object name Event.  Examples: `Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher\Event`, `\Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event `, `Composer\Script\Event`, `Composer\EventDispatcher\Event`

Comment: It is prefixed with member Route::group(['prefix' => 'member',  'as' => 'member.','namespace' => 'Member','middleware' => ['auth']], function() {

Answer (score 0):

It's high chance that delete url you try to send and route url are not the same, please check network and route:list, if not then you probably define your spa route at top, I mean the route except every params

Answer (score 0):

The issue was nothing to do with the routes it was that I was not returning a json response after the delete which was causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way-**

routes `routes/api.php`

```
Route::apiResource('event','EventController');
```

**In Controller Method**

```
public function destroy(Event $event)
    {
        $event->delete();
        return new EventResource($event);
    }
```

**In Your Components**

```
axios.delete('/api/event/'+this.data.module.slug)
     .then(response => {
           console.log(response)
           this.$snotify.success("Data Successfully Delete",'Success')

          })
     .catch(err => {
           console.log(err)
          })
```